# Curve shape paper in css

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-shapes

i need book page turn Animation Effect loading screen . i need curve shape paper like book attached image like that.

in my paper like rectangle how to make cure shape paper

[image]

i set this image as background bub i need paper like that

```css
.paperfixed {
  position: absolute;
  width: 43%;
  background-color: #a92929;
  height: 85%;
  z-index: 0;
  margin: 0px;
  left: 4px;
  top: 6px;
}
.cssload-thecube {
  width: 92px;
  height: 66px;
  margin: auto auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.cssload-thecube .cssload-cube {
  position: relative;
}
.cssload-thecube .cssload-cube {
  float: left;
  width: 51%;
  height: 52%;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
}
.cssload-thecube .cssload-cube:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -37px;
  left: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #e8cfcf;
  animation: cssload-fold-thecube 1s infinite linear both;
  -o-animation: cssload-fold-thecube 1s infinite linear both;
  -ms-animation: cssload-fold-thecube 1s infinite linear both;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-fold-thecube 1s infinite linear both;
  -moz-animation: cssload-fold-thecube 1s infinite linear both;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.cssload-thecube .cssload-c2 {
  transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(90deg);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(90deg);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(90deg);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(90deg);
}
@keyframes cssload-fold-thecube {
  0%, 50% {
    transform: perspective(-180deg) rotateX(-136px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    transform: perspective(136px) rotateX(-180deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.book-bg {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="book">
  <div class="cssload-thecube">
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class="cssload-cube cssload-c2"></div>
  </div>
  <h5>Loading . . .</h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a little look at this and it should you give you some idea of one way to create the curved pages.

This does require a solid background color to create the bottom page curve. Hope you find this helpful.

```css
.book {
  width: 120px;
  margin: 40px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.page {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
}
.page:before, .page:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;

}
.firstPage:before {
  background: #a92929;
  top: -7px;
}
.secondPage:before {
  background: red;
  top: -7px;
}
.page:after {
  background: #fff;
  bottom: -7px;
}
.firstPage {
  background: #a92929;
}
.secondPage {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="book">
  <div class="page firstPage"></div>
  <div class="page secondPage"></div>
</div>
```